# How do you directly write to a request body in Python

Tags: python, csv, request, pycurl, httplib

I am currently implementing code to call out to an API where the post request body needs to contain several columns of data in csv format.

e.g.

`Col1, Col2, Col3`

`1, 2, 3`

`4, 5, 6`

etc, with the content type header is set to 'text/csv'

How do I directly write to the request body?

I have a coworker who is doing the same thing as I am in Java and the Apache httpclient lib simply has a setRequestBody method.

Is there something similar in httplib, urllib (1,2) or pyCurl? Thanks.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this in pyCurl?

Answer (score 2):

Any HTTP client will give you some way to set the request body. For example, [`httplib.HTTPConnection.request`](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPConnection.request) takes an optional `body` parameter that allows you to pass request data. Same with [`urllib2.urlopen`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) (there it's called `data`). I've never used PycURL myself but it definitely provides some way to include a body in the request.